# Complexity of the recurrence T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/2)+n^2?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, recurrence, induction

In accord to Master Theorem this recurrece is θ(n^2), but if we solve this with tree recurrence the solution is θ(n^2*logn). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How can the complexity be less than n^2 if right from the first execution you have a n^2 complexity?

Comment: Your application of Master Theorem is incorrect

Comment: Can you be clearer what the recurrence relation is? Is it T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the recurrence relation is T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^2, then you're in the third case of the master theorem, and the regularity condition applies, so T(n) = Theta(n^2). [c_crit is log_2(2) = 1, n^2 = Omega(n), 2(n/2)^2 = (n^2)/2 (so k<1, specifically k=1/2)]

If you expand out the recurrence relation by hand, then you get:

```
T(n) = n^2 + 2(n/2)^2 + 4(n/4)^2 + 8(n/8)^2 + ...
     = n^2 ( 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)
     <= 2n^2
```

So this method too gives you T(n) = Theta(n^2).

The method of [inputting the recurrence relation into Wolfram Alpha and seeing what it says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%20%3D%202T%28n%2F2%29%20%2B%20n%5E2) gives T(n) ~ 2n^2, so again Theta(n^2).

Comment: @AlfredoMungari if you found the answer helpful and it answered your question, you can consider upvoting the answer and accepting it.

Comment: How I can upvoting the answer and accepting it ? @PaulHankin

Comment: I think I can't upvote this answer because my reputation is less then 15 @PaulHankin